# Downloading files based on most recent date and timestamp

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a requirement to download zipped files from an SFTP site using C# and Script Task within SSIS.

We have multiple files on the server with the same name, but with different date and timestamps.

Is there a way download the files based on most recent date and timestamp?

Comment: Is the file download is done in C# code or you want it to be done by SQL Server

Comment: The download is required to be done in C#

Answer (score 5):

As the [answer by @MarkSinkinson](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/77512/83075#77516) shows, you can use [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library).

There is an official example on WinSCP site for [downloading the most recent file](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_download_most_recent_file).

As it shows, to select and download the most recent file, use:

```csharp
// Get list of files in the directory
RemoteDirectoryInfo directoryInfo = session.ListDirectory(remotePath);

// Select the most recent file
RemoteFileInfo latest =
    directoryInfo.Files
        .Where(file => !file.IsDirectory)
        .OrderByDescending(file => file.LastWriteTime)
        .FirstOrDefault();

// Any file at all?
if (latest == null)
{
    throw new Exception("No file found");
}

// Download the selected file
session.GetFiles(RemotePath.EscapeFileMask(remotePath + latest.Name), localPath).Check();
```

For a full code, see the link.

See also the article on [using the WinSCP .NET assembly from SSIS](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_ssis).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Comment: Better using ***good practices*** with `session.FileTransferred += FileTransferred` and `session.FileTransferProgress`, maybe                     `session.SessionLogPath`, `session.DebugLogLevel` and `session.DebugLogPath`

Answer (score 2):

There may be other ways to do this, but in my previous job we utilised a [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) library through a Script Task to download files from an SFTP.

[You can download the WinSCP library from here.](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/library)

There's some good examples of code on their site, including [listing contents of a directory](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_listdirectory#example):

```
using System;
using WinSCP;

class Example
{
    public static int Main()
    {
        try
        {
            // Setup session options
            SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions {
                Protocol = Protocol.Sftp,
                HostName = "example.com",
                UserName = "user",
                Password = "mypassword",
                SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-rsa 2048 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx"
            };

            using (Session session = new Session())
            {
                // Connect
                session.Open(sessionOptions);

                RemoteDirectoryInfo directory = session.ListDirectory("/home/martin/public_html");

                foreach (RemoteFileInfo fileInfo in directory.Files)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} with size {1}, permissions {2} and last modification at {3}",
                        fileInfo.Name, fileInfo.Length, fileInfo.FilePermissions, fileInfo.LastWriteTime);
                }
            }

            return 0;   
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e);
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully your C# is pretty decent, so you can loop through the LastWriteTime to identify the most recent written file to the server.

Once you've identified the RemotePath you want to download, you would [call the GetFiles method:](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_getfiles#example)

```
// Download the file and throw on any error
session.GetFiles(remotePath, localPath).Check();
```

Obviously you'd then need to put in the SSIS error handling, but I'm hoping you've got this area covered.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem where i had to get the latest files from a SFTP.

At first i did a similar solution as the ones above, but we had some issues with the load not picking up a file if the timing was off for some reason (we needed all the copies on top of the latest). So instead i added a filesync task that basically syncs the files on the server withe local folder.

Could be worth considering. You can set the SynchronizationCriteria to time in your case.

Old code, and @Martin Prikryl probably has a neater way of doing it...
So pardon my C#...

Here is a class using the WinSCP library.

```
public class HostSFTP
{
    public List<string> downloadedFiles = new List<string>();

    public void FileSync(string hostName, string userName, string password, bool GiveUpSecurity, string SshHostKeyFingerprint, int port, string local, string remote, string exe, string fileMask)
    {           
        SessionOptions sOpt = new SessionOptions
        {
            Protocol = Protocol.Sftp,
            HostName = hostName,
            UserName = userName,
            Password = password,
            GiveUpSecurityAndAcceptAnySshHostKey = GiveUpSecurity, -- You can choose to ignore sshhostupdates.
            SshHostKeyFingerprint = SshHostKeyFingerprint,
            PortNumber = port
        };

        try
        {
            using (Session session = new Session())
            {
                session.ExecutablePath = exe;// @"C:\%Program folder%\Winscp\winscp.exe";
                session.FileTransferred += FileTransferred;
                session.Open(sOpt);

                //Sync folders
                TransferOptions transferOpt = new TransferOptions();
                transferOpt.TransferMode = TransferMode.Binary;
                transferOpt.FileMask = fileMask;// @"filename.*|*"  includes | excludes

                SynchronizationResult syncResult;
                syncResult =
                    session.SynchronizeDirectories(
                        SynchronizationMode.Local,
                        local,
                        remote,
                        false,
                        false,
                        SynchronizationCriteria.None,
                        transferOpt);

                syncResult.Check();                  
            }           
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error : {0}", e);
        }
    }

    public void FileTransferred(object sender, TransferEventArgs e)
    {                       
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Download of {0} succeeded", e.FileName);
            downloadedFiles.Add(e.FileName.Replace(@"/", ""));    
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Download of {0} failed: {1}", e.FileName, e.Error);
        }
        if (e.Chmod != null)
        {
            if (e.Chmod.Error == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Permisions of {0} set to {1}", e.Chmod.FileName, e.Chmod.FilePermissions);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Setting permissions of {0} failed: {1}", e.Chmod.FileName, e.Chmod.Error);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Permissions of {0} kept with their defaults", e.Destination);
        }

        if (e.Touch != null)
        {
            if (e.Touch.Error == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Timestamp of {0} set to {1}", e.Touch.FileName, e.Touch.LastWriteTime);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Setting timestamp of {0} failed: {1}", e.Touch.FileName, e.Touch.Error);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // This should never happen with Session.SynchronizeDirectories
            Console.WriteLine("Timestamp of {0} kept with its default (current time)", e.Destination);
        }
    }
}
```